# Oracle - Selecting not null result of calculation

Tags: oracle, select, null

For every row of my data set, there exist data for the only one of the two options for calculation and the other columns are Null.

My goal is to find simplest way to select not null result of calculation for each row. Expected result:

```
ROW_NUM   result
-------- -------
1          4.5
2          4.56
```

My code:

```
With DATASET AS ( 
  -- column 1 is just for row number, 
  -- column 2 and 3 for caculation option1, 
  --- columns 4~6 for caculation option2
  SELECT 1 ROW_NUM, NULL time1, NULL qty1,  2   time2_1, 2.5  time2_2,  1 qty2 
  FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 ROW_NUM, 4.56 time1, 1   qty1,   NULL time2_1, NULL time2_2, NULL qty2 
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ROW_NUM, time1/qty1 OPTION1, (time2_1+time2_2)/qty2 OPTION2 
FROM DATASET;
```

Result:

```
 ROW_NUM   OPTION1 OPTION2
 -------- ------- ---------
    1                4.5
    2      4.56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) and use different representation when null:

```
SELECT ROW_NUM, decode(time1/qty1,null,(time2_1+time2_2)/qty2,time1/qty1) result FROM DATASET;
```

Or [nvl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm)

```
SELECT ROW_NUM, nvl(time1/qty1,(time2_1+time2_2)/qty2,time1/qty1) result FROM DATASET;
```

> NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query.

Answer (score 1):

use `COALESCE` function as following:

```
With DATASET AS ( 
--each row contain information for either option1 or 2 
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
--column 1 is just for row number, column 2 and 3 for caculation option1, columns 4~6 for caculation option2
    SELECT 1 ROW_NUM, NULL time1, NULL qty1 ,  2   time2_1 , 2.5  time2_2,  1    qty2 FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 2 ROW_NUM, 4.56 time1 , 1   qty1 , NULL time2_1 , NULL time2_2 , NULL qty2 FROM DUAL
    ) 
    )SELECT ROW_NUM, coalesce(time1/qty1,(time2_1+time2_2)/qty2) as result FROM DATASET;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37929c308d1f2c5c644bbf00f29281e7)

Cheers!!